# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - Nodejs app's tsc command while git push to dokku

Tags: node.js, typescript, memory-leaks, tsc

**Issue**

I ran into a `JavaScript heap out of memory` when trying to git push to a remote server (dokku). It occurred during the `tsc` command. However, I could run `tsc` perfectly fine in my local machine.

**Things I tried**

1. I have tried increasing the heap memory in package.json by adding `"start": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 dist/index.js",` but still got the same error.
2. Some said the node version might be less than 10 but mine is 16 so it should not be the case.

**Error message**

```
Step 8/15 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Running in f9d0db4c089e
yarn run v1.22.15
$ tsc

<--- Last few GCs --->
io[29:0x485a8a0]    28258 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 490.0 (492.6) -> 489.3 (494.1) MB, 737.1 / 4.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 17 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 940 ms) (average mu = 0.268, current mu = 0.215) allocati[29:0x485a8a0]    29337 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 490.4 (493.1) -> 490.1 (494.6) MB, 681.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 72.0 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 20.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 1078 ms) (average mu = 0.287, current mu = 0.305) alloc

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa389b0 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x96e0af node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0xbb7a4e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0xbb7dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0xd73fd5  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0xd74b5f  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0xd8299b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0xd8655c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0xd54c3b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x109d21f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x1446379  [/usr/local/bin/node]
Aborted (core dumped)
error Command failed with exit code 134.
```

**In my package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
  },
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

  
RUN yarn

COPY . .
COPY .env.production .env

RUN yarn build

ENV NODE_ENV production

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
USER node
```

**Command I ran before getting the error is**

`git push dokku master`
to push to remote dokku hosted by Digital Ocean